# Using an Instantiated Class in another Class

Tags: c#, class, class-design, instantiation

Please excuse my ignorance, I am transitioning from VB6 to C# (very steep learning curve). I have googled this to death and I am not able to figure this out. I instantiated a Class on my main form:

```
namespace App1_Name
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public cConfig Config = new cConfig();
    }
}
```

In my Config Class I am instantiating two other classes:

```
namespace App1_Name
{
    class cConfig
    {
        //Properties
        public cApplication Application = new cApplication();
    }
}
```

In my cApplications Class I have the following:

```
namespace App1_Name
{
    class cApplication
    {
        //Properties
        public string ApplicationName { get { return "App Name"; } }
    }
}
```

So in another class I am looking to use the class I instantiated on Form1 as so:

```
namespace App1_Name
{
    class cXML
    {
        public void Method1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Config.Application.ApplicationName);)
        }
     }
}
```

But I am getting an error that states "Config" doesn't exist in the current context, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't you miss instance of Form1?

```
Form1 form = new Form1();    
Console.WriteLine(form.Config.Application.ApplicationName);
```

because you are working with properties... not static classes and static methods.

Comment: Ok, I tried you example but I am still getting the following error: Error 1 'App1_Name.Form1.Config' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: I guess you are getting error about access. You are missing `public` keyword at your classes (at least `cConfig` and `cApplication`).

Comment: Yea, as I thought... just change your classes to public.. like `public class cConfig`.

Comment: Doh! I can't believe I missed that one. Thanks Everyone! Reputation points for everyone!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Form1.Config.Application.ApplicationName);
```

EDIT: Dampe is correct; you need an instance of Form1, since Config is not a static member of the class.  Please refer to his answer.

Comment: Dang your speed, I was nanoseconds away from posting the same thing :(

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick response, I appreciate it! When I type that in in my XML class I get the following error: "Error 2 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'App1_Name.Form1.Config'"

Comment: @Mark Kram: Check mine solution. I believe you can't call properties without a class instance.

Comment: @Mark Kram: That's because Dampe is right; you need to access an instance of Form1, not the class itself.  Sorry for the misdirection.

Answer (score 1):

All of the above, or a one-liner:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Form1().Config.Application.ApplicationName);
```

Comment: This is of course possible solution in this context. We don't know if he's going to need form reference for anything else later on. (In that case I would prefer creating separate variable.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in order to get my original code to work I made the cApplication Static. This is because I was instantiating the cXML in Form1's Form_Load event so the above solutions just created an endless loop.

What I did to resolve the issue was to pass the Config Class as a reference to the cXML class as follows:

```
namespace App1_Name
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public cConfig Config = new cConfig();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cXML XML = new cXML();
        XML.Config = Config; //Passing the Config Class by Reference to cXML
    }
}
```

In the cXML class I am doing the following:

```
namespace App1_Name
{
    class cXML
    {
        public cConfig Config;

        public string AppName
        {

            Console.WriteLine(Config.Application.AppName);
        }
    }
}
```

This does exactly what I originally set out to do. My new question is is this an acceptable way of doing this?

Comment: Ok, I changed my solution a little, I am now creating the object in the class as follows:

    public cConfig Config = new App1_Name.cConfig();